# How do I make fetch requests to dynamic targets, remote non-cors enabled urls? In http-proxy-middleware, can variables be used in targets?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, reverse-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I use fetch('htp://list-of-servers') that returns a list of urls

- test1.example.com
- test3.example.com
- test5.example.com

Then I need to perform a fetch() on each one of these urls: fetch('test1.example.com').then(...)

```
urls.map(url => fetch(url))
```

but

- a) url is not cors enabled (so I tried adding them in setupProxy)
- b) I don't know these urls in advance (since they're result of an earlier fetch, so I'm not sure how they can be added to setupProxy.js.
  I basically need some kind of equivalent to curl, that can request any non-cors remote url, but in js/react/node.

Suggestions?

Comment: You can do it on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution online. I have to run an express server/node app at the same time as the react client (different port), so client requests to `url=test1.example.com`, would be written as `` fetch(`/api/${url}`) `` then that would hit the express server localhost for proxying, where it would do a non-browser server-side request `` fetch(`http://${url}`) `` where cors problems wouldn't be an issue. I needed an ELI5.